# How do I prevent my page from reloading? (I'm in HTML and I did suggested methods but it did not work)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

My page is reloaded after I press the enter key, and I don't want that to happen. I am not using jQuery. I saw in other places that if I typed `return false` in my `onSubmit`, then it will not reload. This did not work for me.

```
    <form onsubmit="save(); return false" id="form">
        Type Here: <input type="text" id="inInput">
    </form>
```

This is the `save()` function. It is in my javascript.

```
        function save()
        {
            savedVar = document.getElementById("inInput").value;
            document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("printer").innerHTML = savedVar;
            clearInput();
            if (curOp == "v")
            {
                vowelDo();
            }
            else if (curOp == "t")
            {
                translaterDo();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put `return false;` in your `save()` function?